# Modify Conditional Formatting 'AppliesTo' Range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet (lets call it `Sheet1`) which has two existing Conditional Formatting rules. Which apply to a range in column H. The data in `Sheet1` is deleted and new data is input via a database connection. This deletion and retrieval of data means the `RANGE` that the conditional formatting applies to changes. Is there a way I can update the CF formatting `RANGE` (in the `Applies to` box) without deleting it and recreating it in code?

pseudo-code would be something like

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Cells.FormatConditions(1).AppliesTo = "H4:H" & .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
.Cells.FormatConditions(2).AppliesTo = "H4:H" & .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Any help would be appreciated, 
Many Thanks
Caleeco

Comment: I think the solution here is to format paint down from cell H4 to your `Rows.Count` cell

Comment: That is an excellent idea! I will do some testing and mark as solved if I can get it to work. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dwirony. The code below works, posting in case future readers may wish to employ the same method. Feel free to post your own answer and I will mark yours as the solution.

```
Sub FillDown()
'// Fill down formatting to apply CF to entire range
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("H4").Copy
        .Range("H4:H" & .Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The command is "ModifyAppliesToRange". An example of it in use is:

```
Cells.FormatConditions(2).ModifyAppliesToRange Range("X2:Y100")
```

Note that there is no "=" between the ModifyAppliesToRange and the actual range.

Sorry for being 5 years too late...